# python - Object Oriented code for charging

Tags: python

Using python I want to write a code to show deposit and charging of an account. I wrote the following code, but for the charge section I don't know what/how I should write it, I appreciate it if you could tell me how it should be:

```py
class Account:
    last_id = 1000

    def __init__(self, customer):
        self.customer = customer
        Account.last_id += 1
        self.id = Account.last_id
        self._balance = 0

    def deposit(self, amount):
        

        if amount > 0:
            self._balance += amount
            print('Deposit: ' + str(self._balance))
        else:
            print('Operation was successful')


    def charge(self, amount):
        #This one I am not sure about
```

Comment: How do you intend to use this method? Why don't you write it similarly to the deposit one? Do you really want to allow a negative or zero deposit? Same applies to withdrawals.

Comment: What is the `self.id` for? You're not using it at all. `id` is a terrible name, as it's a function from standard library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a birds eye view of the whole thing, it would be hard to give a definitive answer, but I would imagine charging the customer would be done by checking if the customer's balance is more than the charged amount, if its not maybe return some sort of message like: "Customer can't pay the required amount" or make them go into debt. So:

```py
if self._balance < amount:
   print("Customer can't pay the required amount!")
else:
   self._balance = self._balance - amount
```

or just:

```py
self._balance -= amount
```

Also as a side note: I don't recommend asking these sorts of very specific questions, stack overflow is in its own way toxic towards its earlier userbase that asks very specific questions. Try to be more general and use the agreed upon structure of how a question should be asked, using foo bar baz etc.

Comment: Partially agree. SO is being toxic at times and there are a bunch of people dowvoting stuff on daily basis, giving no feedback (which should be banned imho, cause is somebody wants to rant / is frustrated it's a wrong place to be), but...being specific helps. If your question is to general people might not comprehend it and thus give bad/irrelevant answer even if they actuall DO want to help.

Comment: @Gameplay you are 100 % correct, Specifying what you are looking for is great, but I will say it is bad practice to over - specify(something that a lot of newer users do which usually means they get muted for some time(this happened to me actually and is also the reason why I warn people to not replicate my mistakes)) like for example asking questions similar to this one - not a lot of people are going to search specifically for this : |

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making the `_balance` variable private by using double underscore `__balance`.

You can implement the `charge` method as follows:

```
def charge(self, amount):
    if self.__balance < amount:
        print("Not enough balance")
    else:
        self.__balance = self.__balance - amount
```

Other suggestions I would like to provide are -

1. Make the other variables like `customer` private and implement getter and setter methods for them.
2. While writing OOPs code, make use of self-explanatory names for variables. One of the suggestions is already given by **@Gameplay** in the comments.

Comment: python does not have 'private' methods. Using double-underscore is for name-mangling, it does not make it private. Also, one does not write getter and setter methods in Python (python is not Java), but use Property instead.

Comment: Ok, I should have said 'attributes'. But private variables do not exist in Python either. The concept of 'private' does not exist in Python, no matter how many underscores are used.